# Routing in MEAN Stack - Routing help for Angular js and node.js using expressjs framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

> I have solved the problem but I am still unsure if the way I am doing it is correct. If there is any alternative method via which I can send the file and data in one go then that would be more useful. Please give your inputs on the same.

I am using Angular js for the front end and Express js over node.js at the backend.

**What I am trying to do?**

I am trying to implement something like facebook's facility to provide you unique profile names or say user names.

Therefore - The user let's say types domain.com/hisprofileid

Now, what I want to do is a search should be done on the server side which would send response to front end with exact data depending upon the search's result.

and then front end will load the data.

**What I have done till now?**

Honestly speaking I haven't been able to think it out properly and the system I have put in place doesn't work.

This is what I have done. The root call that is `localhost:portnumber` on server side sends a file called index.html. This is just index file and nothing else.

Now on the server side I have made route to handle `localhost:portnumber/anything` which sends profilepage.html file as response.

Now the controller of that profilepage.html's controller using $locationprovider has this code to make a separate call to server side (Please refer to code below) [**I strongly believe this is insignificant and that is why I'm lost**]

Please look at some codes given below.

Front end part

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'index12.html',
        controller: 'someCtrl'
    })
    .when('/:merchantid', {
        templateUrl: 'index12.html',
        controller:'userCtrl'

    })

app.controller('userCtrl', function ($scope, Upload, $timeout, $http) {

    console.log("Here");

    var merchantid = "suresh";
    $http.get('/merchant/' + merchantid ).success(function(response)
    {
        console.log("response");
        console.log(response);
    });
});
```

Server Side

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
     console.log("Global");
     res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index13.html');
});
app.get('/:merchantid', function (req, res) {
     console.log("we are here");
     console.log(req.params); 
      res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index12.html');    
});
app.get('/merchant/:merchantid', function (req, res) {
     console.log("Detail here");
     console.log(req.params); 
     res.json({message: 'here'});       
});
```

Please suggest something.

Comment: What are you getting as the response to your ajax request? are there any errors thrown (express)? Try moving your `/merchant/:merchantid` route above your `/:merchantid` route.

Comment: it is not even called @AshleyB I did what you suggested, still no change.

Comment: Can you check your browser console to make sure the ajax request is actually getting sent?

Comment: that is what I have written in the question above. That specific route in not getting called actually. The server part is only getting called - it skips the front end one.

Comment: Right, it's a bit hard to understand from the question _which_ route isn't working (angular or express). I'd suggest re-wording some of your question to make it a bit clearer.

Comment: Sure. I will do it right away.

Comment: Done @AshleyB. I hope it is easier now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I have done to solve the problem.

`localhost:portnumber/anything` - When this is called I am making a call to the server directly and a check is made if that particular person actually has signed up or not and then based on that result the appropriate page is opened.

```
app.get('/:profileid', route_profileid.fetchprofile);
```

Then the function to handle the data associated with it.

```
modename.findOne({
            'profileid': uniqueid
        }, function (err, docs) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error in finding data" + err);
            } else {
                if (docs) {
                    console.log(process.cwd());
                    res.sendFile(process.cwd() + '/public/profile.html');
                }
                if (!docs) {
                    console.log("Nothing Found related to that query");
                    res.sendFile(process.cwd() + '/public/error.html');
                }
            }
```

Now the profile page is loaded with profile data of that specific used and then here is the code of angular's router. [This angular code is attached to the profile page which will be shown.]

```
 $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function () {
     console.log($routeParams.profileid);
     var profileid = $routeParams.profileid;
     $http.get('/profile/' + profileid).success(function (response) {
         console.log(response);
         $scope.profile = response;
     });
 });
```

Note: Inclusion of `$RouteParams`, `$route`, `$routeScope` and ngRoute module to facilitate the activity is required.

Here a new request is made for the actual data of that user.

```
 app.get('/profileid/:profileid', route_profiledata.profiledata);
```

and then in that specific function data is fetched from the db and appropriate response is sent back to the user.